# How to add user authentication to docsifyjs

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, docsify

I am using [docsifyjs](https://docsify.js.org/) to create a documentation. But I wanted to add Authentication to access the docs.

Basically we serve the docs with following commands

**Initializing docsify**

```
docsify init ./docs
```

After the init is complete, you can see the file list in the ./docs subdirectory.

`index.html` as the entry file
`README.md` as the home page
`.nojekyll` prevents GitHub Pages from ignoring files that begin with an underscore

We can now serve the mark-down files as HTML with following commands.

```
docsify serve docs
```

or

```
cd docs && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000
```

or

```
npx http-server docs
```

Here docsify is served by giving the path of initialized directory.

But I am not able to figure out how to serve this with **expressJS**. So that I can add authentication.
I have tried adding **app.js** to **./docs** and added the following code but markdown files are not being rendered.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = express();

app.use(serveStatic('/', { 'index': ['index.html', 'index.htm'] }));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
})
app.listen(8000);
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Comment: It is a static site generator. As fas as my research I got know we must write a proxy script for it and add authentication. But didn't find the exact solution.

Comment: This is exactly what Im trying to do but I can't figure out how.  I was told there may be a way to do it with Request headers but there is limited documentation on it https://docsify.js.org/#/configuration?id=requestheaders

Comment: @Alexy Nope. I didnt find it yet